# GNU - Undefined Reference to `setmode'

Tags: c, linux, gnu, porting

I am porting a WIN32 library on Linux. I am able to compile my library with no error. But when i try to link, it gives following linking error

> undefined reference to `setmode'

I know that **setmode** function is standard library function and it resides in **unistd.h** and i provide the argument **-lc** while linking through terminal.

This is the [link](http://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/3/SETMODE/) which lightened more about **setmode**.

Is there any help for the same?

Comment: Can you pls post the error which you are getting?

Comment: the highlighted portion is linking error only. I have mentioned that i'm getting this linking error :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setmode` isn't a standard library function; it's a libbsd function. That's only the same thing on BSD-derived systems like OS X, which that man page is from. Pass the `-lbsd` argument to get the linker to find it on Linux.

Always trust your own system's man pages over the Internet's.

Comment: it is not able to find setmode even after -lbsd argument is passed. :-(

Comment: Are you sure you have libbsd installed? Does the linker complain about the `-lbsd` flag itself?

Comment: No linker does not complain about -lbsd flag. So it is installed.

Comment: Here its magic, if i remove reference to unistd.h file, the source still compiles successfully. Its weird !!!

Comment: That *is* weird. Which distro are you using?

Comment: Pardon, i did not get the meaning of "distro" !

Comment: Linux distribution. Like Debian or RHEL or Arch Linux.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26838/discussion-between-jparthj-and-cairnarvon)

Comment: If the program is coming from Windows, it might be relying on the Cygwin `setmode` function, which is something entirely different. The linking may work, but the program is incorrect.

Answer (score 8):

I'm afraid these answers are nonsense. A program coming from the Win32 environment is using one of two possible `setmode` functions: either the Microsoft `_setmode` function [documented in MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tw4k6df8.aspx), or the Cygwin imitation of it called `setmode`.

This has nothing to do with the BSD `setmode`. It's a two-argument function which sets a file descriptor to either binary or text translation mode.

**If your program expects this function, but you link to LibBSD, the program might link, but it is not correct.**

The GNU C library doesn't provide an interface for manipulating the text or binary mode of `FILE *` streams or descriptors, and if it did, it wouldn't do anything, since the two modes are identical.

Code that needs the Cygwin `setmode` function on Cygwin can probably just get away with not doing anything on Unix: so that is to say:

```
#ifdef __CYGWIN__
setmode(fileno(my_stdio_stream), O_BINARY);
#elif _WIN32
_setmode(_fileno(my_stdio_stream), _O_BINARY);
#else
/* nothing on systems with no text-vs-binary mode */
#endif
```

Answer (score 4):

I had trouble with this one too; the linking happens during the make process, so this will occur and people who have no business dealing with c (like me) try to use cygwin or mingw.  Thanks to Cairnarvon's answer, I learned that a necessary include statement was missing:

```
#include <io.h>
```

...in modules which call the `setmode` function (in my case, I am trying to build GDAL on Cygwin 64 bit).  The error remained, until I saw [these folks](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-bug-tracker/2013-07/msg00069.html)' answer and learned that the 64 bit version of Cygwin does not prepend underscores the way that the 32 bit version does.  So I did the prepending manually and the make finished [more] successfully. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `<bsd/unistd.h>` header (not `<unistd.h>`).

On my Ubuntu box, I had to install packages `libbsd0` and `libbsd-dev`:

```
sudo apt-get install libbsd0 libbsd-dev
```

After that, I was able to compile following program:

```
#include <bsd/unistd.h>

int main(void) {
    setmode(0);
    return 0;
}
```

using command:

```
gcc hello.c -lbsd
```

Comment: He's getting a *linker* error, so whatever `unistd.h` he's using already knows about `setmode`.

Comment: In plain C, you *can* use function call like `setmode()` (even if this function is not defined anywhere!) and still have it *compiled* if warnings are turned off. However, it will fail at *linking* stage.